# Restricting one variable in my variable vector to integer in Pyomo

Tags: optimization, pyomo, mixed-integer-programming

I have a minimization problem that currently has only continuous variables

```
min Cx
s.t. Ax <= b
lb <= x <= ub
```

Where C is my cost vector, A is my coefficient matrix and b is my fixed vector. X is my variable vector of continuous variables.

A = 24x29, x = 29x1, b = 24x1

I want to force one of the x variables to be an integer, how can that be done in Pyomo?

I am new to the package, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pyomo offers a way to set the domain of your variables. Let me prove it to you in this example that you can entirely run in a Python console with copy/paste.

Suppose you want to change `x[1]` to integers, you can use (`1` being part of set `S = {1,2,3}`):

```
from pyomo.environ import ConcreteModel, Set, Var, Integers
# Create your model here (set params, vars, constraint...)
model = ConcreteModel()
model.S = Set(initialize={1,2,3})
model.x = Var(model.S)
```

Let's pause the example here and type `model.x.display()` in the Python console. You should see that the domain of all elements in `model.x` is set by default to `Real`. Let's continue.

```
# Here, we suppose your model is created.
# You can change the domain of one lement of your var using this line:
model.x[1].domain = Integers
```

Now, type `model.x.display()` in your Python console and you should see this:

```
x : Size=3, Index=S
Key : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
  1 :  None :  None :  None : False :  True : Integers
  2 :  None :  None :  None : False :  True :    Reals
  3 :  None :  None :  None : False :  True :    Reals
```

So, only `x[1]` is integer.

Answer (score 0):

In practice, we never mix continuous variables with integer variables. So for practical models, it is not a real restriction that we declare variables to be continuous or integer by their name. This rule is not exclusive to Pyomo. Modeling tools like AMPL and GAMS use the same paradigm.

Having said that, let's focus on your problem.

One way to tackle this, would be:

1. Create a single, scalar integer variable y.
2. Add the constraint `y = x[342]` (or whatever the x variable you want to be integer valued)

This is not as crazy as it sounds. A good MIP solver will presolve this away, so the performance impact should be minimal.